# How to redirect specific FOLDER to index.php

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Hi i have this web sctructure:

```
/css/
/js/
/img/
/dashboard/
/pages/
/index.php
```

I got this .htaccess file

```
# Setting default charset
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /web
RewriteRule ^([\w\-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1
</IfModule>
```

Works ok, if i write 
        myurl/login redirect to index.php?page=login
but i wanna to redirect this 
        myurl/dashboard to index.php?module=dashboard
and 
        myurl/dashboard/login to index.php?module=dashboard&page=login

but isnt work with my .htaccess, can you help me? im trying redirecto ALL to index.php but doesnt work, cause redirect /img, /js, /css folder to index.php and i cant see my web

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /web/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(dashboard)/?$ index.php?module=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(dashboard)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?module=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```